# Why does Ajax never return a value even with callbacks

Tags: ajax

Ajax never returns a value. I have tried setting the async:false option and also tried to setup a callback function it still never returns a value. When i browse to the url using firefox i see the expected response but when i make the request via ajax, there is no reponse. Firebug also confirms it.

I have tried lots of code samples i found but they never return a value. I have also tried using a different version jquery and other browsers.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?
Thanks
Below is the code that gets called when a user clicks a button on the form.

```
function login() {
    var username = $("#uname").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/mConnect/login.php',
        data: { username: username, password: password },
        async: false,
        success: function(html) {
            slim(html);
        }
    });
}

function slim(html) {
    // var data = $(xml).find("Status").text();
    alert(html.responseText);
}
```

Below is the login.php it just prints static xml

```
<?php  
    $array = array('stat'  => '1.0',
                    'mode'   => 'whatever',
                    'content' => 'All');

    $new ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><response>';

    foreach($array as $key => $values) {
        $new .= "<$key>$values</$key>";
    }
    echo $new.'</response>';
?>
```

Comment: Please post some code to demonstrate what you are trying to do, otherwise it's almost impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Ajax in general ?! Or do you have maybe a specific piece of code that you want to show us?

Comment: Trust me people are willing to help you but you can really help then understand you problem by providing code samples and more specific details as by looking at the description its hard to make out what is your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a success callback, but no failure callback.  Probably something along the way is failing and there are about 100 possibilities.  Run it in Firebug (or equivalent) and see what happens to the request.  (My money: your local webserver isn't responding at all.)

Comment: OP -- thanks for accepting my answer, but I'm curious: what was actually wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you sent an AJAX request you will get a response. Even if it is a **timeout**. So if you don't have a response at all then you more than likely never sent the request.